# error while converting raster to dataframe

Tags: r, terra

I have a spatraster

```
library(terra)
    
r
    
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 6000, 6000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.0008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 89.99958, 94.99958, 4.999583, 9.999583  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : memory 
name        : SSP_2050 
min value   : 0.0100 
max value   : 0.2376
```

When I try to convert it into dataframe, I get below error:

```
r_df <- terra::as.data.frame(r, xy = T, na.rm = F)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 36000000, 43596000
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: can you convert your data to a simple feature data frame?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: i never worked much with `terra`. best bet would be to try with `sf::st_as_sf()` like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/351689/converting-raster-layer-to-simple-feature-in-r)

Comment: What do you get with `as.array(r)`.

Comment: try `terra::as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE, na,rm = NA)`, (as this is one layer, NA or TRUE for na.rm would have the same result). 36000000 = nrow(r)*ncol(r), and where did 43596000 come from? don't know, but it finds it's way to the data.frame test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug and this is not the place to report that. (See [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/index.html) for where to go)

Either way, I cannot reproduce this. Can you create a reproducible example that creates this error? Are you perhaps using an old version of "terra"? And what does this return? `length(values(r))`. I am guessing that it is `43596000` where it should be `36000000`. How was your `r` created?

```
library(terra)
terra 1.6.17
r <- rast(ncol=5, nrow=2)
values(r) <- 1:10
r[1:2] <- NA
as.data.frame(r, xy=T, na.rm=T) |> head()
#     x   y lyr.1
#3    0  45     3
#4   72  45     4
#5  144  45     5
#6 -144 -45     6
#7  -72 -45     7
#8    0 -45     8
```

Here is a work-around

```
p <- as.points(r)
x <- cbind(crds(p), values(p))
head(x)
#     x   y lyr.1
#1    0  45     3
#2   72  45     4
#3  144  45     5
#4 -144 -45     6
#5  -72 -45     7
#6    0 -45     8
```